# I would require assistance in using LISTAGG function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT pid
       ,LISTAGG(DISTINCT acc_no, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY acc_no) 
        AS acc_no_txt
FROM
(SELECT pid
      ,CASE WHEN acc_no_v01 IN ('not found','blank','nil-value','',' ','null') THEN 'Acc Nbr Not Enterered'
       ELSE acc_no_v01
       END
       AS acc_no
      ,MIN(TRY_TO_NUMBER(T2.vp_no)) AS vp_no
FROM table_1 T1
JOIN table_2 T2
ON T2.click_stream_integration_id = T1.click_stream_integration_id
WHERE T2.date = '2022-01-01'
AND pid='123456789'
GROUP BY pid,acc_no_v01
ORDER BY TRY_TO_NUMBER(vp_no)
)
GROUP BY pid;
```

When I'm running the above query, I'm getting result as mentioned below:

```
PID                          ACC_NO_TXT

123456789              12244059141,Acc Nbr Not Enterered
```

I would like to display the result as shown below:

```
PID                          ACC_NO_TXT

123456789              12244059141
```

I don't want to display - Acc Nbr Not Enterered

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace 'Acc Nbr Not Enterered' in your case statement with NULL

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why he didn't post it as an answer but you can do what Dean Flinter said:

```
SELECT pid
       ,LISTAGG(DISTINCT acc_no, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY acc_no) 
        AS acc_no_txt
FROM
(SELECT pid
      ,CASE WHEN acc_no_v01 IN ('not found','blank','nil-value','',' ','null') THEN NULL
       ELSE acc_no_v01
       END
       AS acc_no
      ,MIN(TRY_TO_NUMBER(T2.vp_no)) AS vp_no
FROM table_1 T1
JOIN table_2 T2
ON T2.click_stream_integration_id = T1.click_stream_integration_id
WHERE T2.date = '2022-01-01'
AND pid='123456789'
GROUP BY pid,acc_no_v01
ORDER BY TRY_TO_NUMBER(vp_no)
)
GROUP BY pid;
```

Comment: Thanks Gokhan! Wasn't sure if such a short answer warranted it's own post!